# What does <asp:View ID="vwReg" runat="server"> mean in an ASP.NET website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone tell me what the `asp:view` control is used for in ASP.NET?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.view.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Represents a control that acts as a container for a group of controls within a [MultiView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview.aspx) control.

You can get details on this control here -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.view.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The View control is a container for a group of controls. A View control must always be contained within a MultiView control. Only one View control at a time can be defined as the active view within a MultiView control.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.view.aspx) - Further Information can be found here.